# Newly created index not appearing

Tags: sql-server

Here's a weird thing: In SQL Server 2017 Standard, I created a new index on one of my tables which already had a few indexes on it, by running the following in SSMS:

```
create unique index UQ_GtsCbotCurve_InvCatProTypMdOd
ON GtsCbotCurve (InventoryId, CategoryId, ProviderId, TypeId, MarkDate, ObservationDate)
```

SSMS said "Query executed successfully".

I hit F5 to refresh SSMS's view of the table, but the new index did not appear in the Indexes node under that table in the object explorer.

I listed the indexes on the table using the system catalog tables like this:

```
select *
from sys.indexes ix
     inner join sys.objects ob on ix.object_id = ob.object_id
where ob.name = 'GtsCbotCurve'
```

and the new index did not appear there.

But when I rerun the `create index` statement, it errors out, saying "an index or statistics with that name already exists on GtsCbotCurve".

I disconnected from the server, and reconnected, but the index still doesn't appear.

What could be going on here? Does the index actually exist? How do I get it to appear in the management tools?

Comment: Perhaps you created the index in a different database (or even server) from the one you were looking at in the explorer pane. Alternatively, you have multiple tables of the same name but in different schemas and you're looking at the wrong object in the explorer pane.

Comment: Hmm. I've only got 2 servers, and I checked both of them. Didn't appear on either one. And wouldn't it still show up in that `select from sys.indexes ...` query even if I got the schema wrong, since that's only filtering on the object name, and not the schema it lives in?

Comment: It absolutely should show up in sys.indexes. If it's not there, that's a pretty strong indication that @SMor got it right.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you had just an empty space highlighted in **SSMS** when you ran the query? If so, it'll still say "*query executed successfully*" even though nothing actually executed. If you're able to create the index now, then it definitely didn't create the first time.

Comment: I don't think so; because when I ran the "CREATE INDEX" statement again, it errored out with a message saying "A statistics or index with the name UQ_GtsCbotCurve_InvCatProTypMdOd already exists...", which suggests to me that something happened the first time I ran it...

Comment: @AndrewJanke Then that means you definitely created the index. If it's not on the table you suspect, it's on another table in the same database, otherwise you wouldn't receive that error.